# How to incorporate UPS, FED-EX and USPS tracking numbers in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, tracking, ups

The goal is be able to have in column A the tracking number and in column B the status for that tracking number.

I found the code below in a YouTube video but looks like it doesn't work any more:

```
<i>=(IMPORTXML("https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=loc=en_TR&trackNums="&A3, "//*[@id='tt_spStatus']"))</i>
```

Answer (score 2):

## USPS

For tracking USPS packages in a Google Sheet, you'll need a free Web Tools API account which you can set up here: https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/

For their API, documentation is here: https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/track-and-confirm.pdf

One you create an account, you'll get an email within a minute or two, which includes your username. The username they email you will be your user ID.

In Google Sheets, this cell formula should work to concatenate the URL encoded API URL and XML response, with your user ID and the tracking number, assuming you have your tracking number in cell A2, and your API Key / User ID in Cell F2.

```
=Index(IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=TrackV2&XML=%3CTrackRequest%20USERID=%22", $F$1, "%22%3E%3CTrackID%20ID=%22",A3,  "%22%3E%3C/TrackID%3E%3C/TrackRequest%3E"), "/TrackResponse/TrackInfo/TrackSummary[1]"),1)
```

**Note**: the above example assumes you want the most recent tracking status event and uses the XPath `/TrackResponse/TrackInfo/TrackSummary[1]`

## UPS

You can get more information on their official API here: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US

If you need to get something up and running quickly, looking at REST calls happening on ups.com, you should be able to write a Google Script (Tools --> Script Editor), to make an unauthenticated POST request to: https://www.ups.com/track/api/Track/GetStatus?loc=en_US

With the payload:

```
{"TrackingNumber":["1Z1234567890"]}
```

assuming your tracking number is 1Z1234567890

## FedEx

Similar to UPS, for information on their official tracking API you can find that here: https://www.fedex.com/en-us/developer.html

For the quick solution, looking at FedEx page loads, you can also do similar REST calls (assuming your tracking number is 32123312321):

- URL: https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track
- Request content type: `x-www-form-urlencoded`
- Body will look like this:

  - `version`: `1`
  - `action`: `trackpackages`
  - `locale`: `en_US`
  - `format`: `json`
  - `data`: `{"TrackPackagesRequest":{"appType":"WTRK","appDeviceType":"DESKTOP","supportHTML":true,"supportCurrentLocation":true,"uniqueKey":"","processingParameters":{},"trackingInfoList":[{"trackNumberInfo":{"trackingNumber":"32123312321","trackingQualifier":"","trackingCarrier":""}}]}}`
- Response will be JSON hence: `format=json`

That should be wrap-able in a Google Script as well.

Happy Tracking!

Answer (score 1):

```
Index(IMPORTXML("https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums="&A1,"//*[@id='tt_spStatus']"),1)
```

:)